# Sql polygon query taking to long to execute with subquery

Tags: mysql, polygon

I`m starting with sql geography and I made a query to get all the stored points that are inside a polygon sent, it gets the right results but its taking to long to execute. How can I make a better performance to this query?

PS: I`m using mysql on 5.5.62.

My query:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM geolocations 
WHERE id in ( SELECT geo_id FROM users) AND
CONTAINS(GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((-22.892726399999997 -47.05525290000003,-22.891496748403178 -47.05564986693423,-22.8915264 -47.05405289999999,-22.892726399999997 -47.05405289999999,-22.892726399999997 -47.05525290000003))'), coords)   
ORDER BY `id` desc LIMIT 0, 10
```

Edit: If I remove `id in ( SELECT geo_id FROM users)` my query goes faster.

Comment: do you have an index for the geo_id column?

Comment: no, lol thanks, I had forgotten that

Comment: I am adding it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an **index** to `geo_id` column.

Indexes are usually saved in a balanced tree, so the `id in ( SELECT geo_id FROM users)` would have a complexity of a tree search which should be **O(log n)** instead of **O(n)** which should result in better performance.